# Implementing simple dual port block ram in VHDL not performing as expected

Tags: vhdl, ram

I have been trying to implement a simple dual port block RAM in VHDL but it does not yield the expected results in simulation. Here is the code:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.std_logic_unsigned.all;

entity rams is
generic ( g_adress_width: integer:= 18;
          g_ram_size: integer:= 1000
        );
 port(
    clka : in std_logic;
    clkb : in std_logic;
    wea : in std_logic;
    web : in std_logic;
    addra : in std_logic_vector(g_adress_width-1 downto 0);
    addrb : in std_logic_vector(g_adress_width-1 downto 0);
    dia : in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
    dib : in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
    doa : out std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
    dob : out std_logic_vector(15 downto 0));
end rams;
architecture syn of rams is
    type ram_type is array (g_ram_size-1 downto 0) of std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
     signal RAM : ram_type; 
begin
 process (CLKA)
 begin
    if CLKA'event and CLKA = '1' then
            DOA <= RAM(conv_integer(ADDRA));
            if WEA = '1' then --always 0
                RAM(conv_integer(ADDRA)) <= DIA; --does not execute
        end if;
    end if;
 end process;

 process (CLKB)
 begin
 if CLKB'event and CLKB = '1' then
        DOB <= RAM(conv_integer(ADDRB));
        if WEB = '1' then
            RAM(conv_integer(ADDRB)) <= DIB;
    end if;
 end if;

end process;
end syn;
```

And here is the simulation:

[image: Simulation]

Both **clka** and **clkb** are connected to the same clock. I give some arbitrary values (unsigned 300 and 355) to **dib**.

Basically, **doa** is always reading so I expect it to be undefined until something has been written to those block ram addresses with **dib**, but it is showing undefined values always.

What I expect to happen is for **doa** to read 300 when **addra** is at 0 again and to read 355 when **addra** is at 15. Something like this (pardon my paint skills):

[image]

Would appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction of what I am doing wrong. Thanks.

**EDIT: Code is modified to this and it works now (thanks to Paebbels solution):**

```
     signal RAM : ram_type; 
begin
 process (CLKA)
 begin
    if CLKA'event and CLKA = '1' then
            DOA <= RAM(to_integer(unsigned(ADDRA)));
            if WEA = '1' then --always 0
                    RAM(to_integer(unsigned(ADDRA))) <= DIA; --does not happen
        end if;

    end if;

    if CLKA'event and CLKA = '1' then
        DOB <= RAM(to_integer(unsigned(ADDRB)));
        if WEB = '1' then
            RAM(to_integer(unsigned(ADDRB))) <= DIB;
    end if;
 end if;

 end process;
end syn;
```

Comment: I have two questions: 1- Can't you show the RAM signal in your wave ? 2- Don't you get a multiple driver warning on the signal RAM? if yes, how do you manage it ?

Comment: Hi, the tool doesn't support showing this RAM signal as far as I know. And I do not get warnings for this, normally i wouldn't put a same signal assignment on two different processes but looking online this seems to be the standard way of implementing dual port block ram...

Comment: Can you post your testbench ? I'm curious to test it with modelsim. Also, are you using the Xilinx tool ?

Comment: By the way: If you are using Vivado then you can display an array.

Comment: Be careful, in your modified code, you have only one clock instead of two in your first attempt...

Comment: @grorel, sorry I unfortunately cannot publish our testbench here. I am using Xilinx ISE. 

In the modified code, I made it intentional to only have one clock for this specific task (both clock a and clock b are attached to the same input clock, i could have made this clearer, my bad). Do you still see a problem with it if I intended to only use the one clock?
I can make this code cleaner for sure... like now I have two if statements checking for the same clock edge, I can make it only one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This description of a dual-clock RAM is wrong. You need to use either:

- a process with two clocks, or
- a shared variable.

Using one signal and two processes ist not correct. It creates multiple drives on a signal. This in turn creates a multiple source problem. While your simulation will work, because of the resolved type `std_logic_vector` in your user defined array type, synthesis will fail.

In addition, to allow inference of BlockRAMs, you need to represent the internal structure of BlockRAMs in you VHDL code. This means you need to add pipeline registers on the address path.

You should read [UG901 - Vivado Synthesis Guide](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx2018_1/ug901-vivado-synthesis.pdf) and search for "RAM HDL Coding Techniques".

Further more, you should use package `numeric_std` instead of `std_logic_unsigned`, which is not an official IEEE package.

---

A working true-dual-port (TDP) BlockRAM implementation can be found in the [PoC-Library](https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC): [PoC.mem.ocram.tdp](https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC/blob/master/src/mem/ocram/ocram_tdp.vhdl?ts=2#L136-L168). This implementation will also work on Altera/Intel FPGAs and on Lattice FPGAs.

```
    -- RAM can be inferred correctly only if '-use_new_parser yes' is enabled in XST options
    subtype word_t is std_logic_vector(D_BITS - 1 downto 0);
    type    ram_t  is array(0 to DEPTH - 1) of word_t;

    signal ram          : ram_t;
    signal a1_reg       : unsigned(A_BITS-1 downto 0);
    signal a2_reg       : unsigned(A_BITS-1 downto 0);

begin

    process (clk1, clk2)
    begin   -- process
        if rising_edge(clk1) then
            if ce1 = '1' then
                if we1 = '1' then
                    ram(to_integer(a1)) <= d1;
                end if;

                a1_reg <= a1;
            end if;
        end if;

        if rising_edge(clk2) then
            if ce2 = '1' then
                if we2 = '1' then
                    ram(to_integer(a2)) <= d2;
                end if;

                a2_reg <= a2;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;

    q1 <= (others => 'X') when SIMULATION and is_x(std_logic_vector(a1_reg)) else
                ram(to_integer(a1_reg));        -- returns new data
    q2 <= (others => 'X') when SIMULATION and is_x(std_logic_vector(a2_reg)) else
                ram(to_integer(a2_reg));        -- returns new data
```

Comment: Hey man, thanks. This worked. 
I changed my code to be only one process with the one clock:

process(CLKA) 

and I am using numeric_std now.

I am showing the modified code in my main post. Would you mind taking a look at it?